# How can I immediately play a sound when another sound ends using XNA/XACT?

Tags: c#, audio, xna, xact

This question borders between the world of the audio designer and the programmer. While this question might have to be partially answered by that domain of an audio designer, it is sure a problem for the programmer. In our project, we want to loop a sound (background music) while the game timer is greater than one minute left. When this time is hit, we wish to stop the music as authored, **and then immediately continue with ending segment**. I have been looking into XACT, and it seems to have support for different events. Unfortunately, the documentation is lacking, and the application is somewhat alien to me as a programmer.

What I am looking to do is something along these lines (different approaches):

1. When the music stops, I want to tie
   an event to play another sound
   immediately
2. When a marker is
   triggered in the music, I want to
   play another sound immediately
3. I would also like to know in my application when some of these events happen

The problem is that I haven't been able to find any mechanism to auto-play sound when another sound begins and that I can't find a way to hook up with the events made in the XACT project to C#.

If this can't be done (i.e. XACT/XNA lacks support for these operations), please gather your ideas on how to solve this problem with minimal cross-sound time errors. Preferably I would be able to control this as much as possible in C# with calls to XNA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I think I've solved it now

Here's how I did it.

1. Select the **Cue** which you want to change sound after it has been stopped in **XACT**.
2. Set **Playlist Type** to **Interactive**.
3. Open Cue **Transitions**.
4. Select **View by Destination**.
5. Select the **Cue** in the **(stop)** node visible in the tree view.
6. In **Transition Properties** at the right side of the tree view, for **Source and Destination**:

   1. Set **Source** to **End of Loop**.
   2. Set **Destiantion** to **Beginning**.
7. In **Transition Properties** at the right side of the tree view, for **Transitions**:

   1. Set **Transition Type** to **Direct Concurrent Transition**.
   2. Set **Transitional Sound** to **the sound you wish to play** after the looping sound has completed its loop.

Close the window and test it by playing the Cue. Also test to stop it **As Authored** to see if the behaviour fulfilles your expectations.

---

### Implementation

In code, **Stop** the Cue **As Authored** to get this behaviour. **Immediate** stops the cue without playing the sound outro. I hope this helps other people who might run into this problem in the future. The question and answer wasn't that much code oriented as I thought initially. Also, this applies for XNA 2.0. I don't know if there will be other options for controlling this kind of behaviour in XNA 3.0+.

Comment: Excellent answer! I'm loving the layout. +1